# How to find min-max occurrence of an element in xsd using xsom

Tags: java, xsd, schema, xsom

I want to find out the minimum occurence maximm occurence of an xsd element using xsom of java.I got this code to find out complex elements.Can anyone help me in find out occurence of all the xsd element.Atlest give me a code snippet with the class and method to be used to find the occurrence

```
xmlfile = "Calendar.xsd"
XSOMParser parser = new XSOMParser();

parser.parse(new File(xmlfile));
XSSchemaSet sset = parser.getResult();
XSSchema s = sset.getSchema(1);
if (s.getTargetNamespace().equals("")) // this is the ns with all the stuff
       // in
{
  // try ElementDecls
  Iterator jtr = s.iterateElementDecls();
  while (jtr.hasNext())
  {
    XSElementDecl e = (XSElementDecl) jtr.next();
    System.out.print("got ElementDecls " + e.getName());
    // ok we've got a CALENDAR.. what next?
    // not this anyway
    /*  
     *
     * XSParticle[] particles = e.asElementDecl() for (final XSParticle p :
     * particles) { final XSTerm pterm = p.getTerm(); if
     * (pterm.isElementDecl()) { final XSElementDecl ed =
     * pterm.asElementDecl(); System.out.println(ed.getName()); }
     */
  }

  // try all Complex Types in schema
  Iterator<XSComplexType> ctiter = s.iterateComplexTypes();
  while (ctiter.hasNext())
  {
    // this will be a eSTATUS. Lets type and get the extension to 
    // see its a ENUM
    XSComplexType ct = (XSComplexType) ctiter.next();
    String typeName = ct.getName();
    System.out.println(typeName + newline);

    // as Content
    XSContentType content = ct.getContentType();
    // now what?
    // as Partacle?
    XSParticle p2 = content.asParticle();
    if (null != p2)
    {
      System.out.print("We got partical thing !" + newline);
      // might would be good if we got here but we never do :-(
    }

    // try complex type Element Decs
    List<XSElementDecl> el = ct.getElementDecls();
    for (XSElementDecl ed : el)
    {
      System.out.print("We got ElementDecl !" + ed.getName() + newline);
      // would be good if we got here but we never do :-(
    }

    Collection<? extends XSAttributeUse> c = ct.getAttributeUses();
    Iterator<? extends XSAttributeUse> i = c.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext())
    {
      XSAttributeDecl attributeDecl = i.next().getDecl();
      System.out.println("type: " + attributeDecl.getType());
      System.out.println("name:" + attributeDecl.getName());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to com.sun.xml.xsom, the occurrence is specific to a particle (elements are not the only particles).

Here are the APIs: [maxOccurs](http://xsom.java.net/nonav/javadoc/com/sun/xml/xsom/XSParticle.html#getMaxOccurs%28%29) and [minOccurs](http://xsom.java.net/nonav/javadoc/com/sun/xml/xsom/XSParticle.html#getMinOccurs%28%29)

For one source to see how to traverse a schema tree using XSOM please take a look [here](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-xjc/2.1.8/jaxb-xjc-2.1.8-sources.jar!/com/sun/xml/xsom/impl/util/SchemaTreeTraverser.java?format=ok). It shows basically how the visitor patterns works with XSOM (for which Sun built a package).